# Trying to demonstrate a seemingly trivial proof in measure theory

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I've been trying to understand how to answer this basic exercise:

Show that if $A, B  \in \chi $ and $A \subset B$, then $\mu(A) \leq \mu(B)$.

where $(X, \chi)$ is a measurable space, and $\mu$ is a measure.

I'm very new to measure theory, and am not sure how to demonstrate a proof that this statement is true, despite it's seemingly trivial nature. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hint: $B$ is the disjoint union $
A\cup( B\setminus A)$

Comment: $\mu(B)=\mu(B \backslash A)+\mu(A)\ge\mu(A)$

Comment: @Thomas thank you both for the replies. Can you clarify what the backslash notation means here?

Comment: Set complement, also denoted $B - A$. The points in $B$ which aren't in $A$.